# Eliminar arrays de objetos con id

Tags: javascript, array, jsonobject, array-bidimensional

No sé si esta pregunta sea duplicada, pero he buscado mucho y no doy con la respuesta:

Tengo una especie de Shopping Cart que funciona de manera gráfica. El usuario traza un círculo y se envía un arreglo con los productos dentro del radio del círculo para almacenarlos en otro arreglo. El círculo puede ser editado agregándole una etiqueta y al ser dibujado, se le genera un identificador. El problema es que cada que se mueve un poco el círculo o se le añade una etiqueta, se crea un nuevo array de objetos. Necesito que al hacer un nuevo push a ese arreglo de Shopping cart, elimine el arreglo anterior si el nuevo ID está repetido de manera que quede el elemento más nuevo.
Adjunto código:

```
const addProductRuta = (productsRutas, etiqueta, identificador)=>{ //cada que un círculo es creado o editado, se llama esta función
    const addRutasFormat=[];
    productsRutas.forEach(element=>{  //recorro el arreglo con las propiedades de los productos por cada producto.
        const medios={
                  id:element.id,
                 nombre:element.nombre,
                 tipoexhib:element.ubicacion.tipoexhib,
                 descripcion:element.descripcion,
                 cantidad: 1,
                 preciourbano:element.ubicacion.preciourbano,
                 descuentoR: 0,
                 inicio: element.inicio,
                 fin: element.fin,
                 fecha_inicio:fecha,
                 fecha_fin:tomorrow,
                 puntos:element.puntos,
                 ubicacion: element.ubicacion.nombre
        }
         addRutasFormat.push(identificador,etiqueta,medios); //creo el objeto añadiendo a los props el identificador del círculo y la etiqueta
    });

    ArrRutas.push(addRutasFormat); //Arreglo donde almaceno cada círculo
    }
```

Adjunto una imagen con mis outputs:
[image: Output]

Como pueden ver, sólo hay un círculo (puede haber N) y en consola imprimí el arreglo `ArrRutas` el cual me trae el círculo *sin etiqueta* y después *con etiqueta.* Y no sé cómo eliminar el antiguo para que sólo quede el nuevo.

Agradezco de antemano sus respuestas.

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento para lograr lo que necesitas? Solo veo el código que agrega el objeto

Answer (score 1):

Todo se resume a que debes enviar el id del círculo creado, y verificar si ese id ya existe en tu arreglo, de no existir se agrega y si existe lo reemplazas, no lo eliminas y creas de nuevo

```
const handleClick = () => {
    const character = {
      id: 1,
      name: "Gohan",
      ki: 20000
    };
    let clone = [...data];

    const index = data.findIndex((x) => x.id === character.id);
    
    if (index < 0) clone.push(character);
    else clone[index] = character;

    setData(clone);
  };
```

En el código anterior, al momento de clickear el botón, este trata de ingresar un objeto nuevo, donde el **id** ya existe, pero sus propiedades **name** y **ki** se actualizan; entonces buscamos si ese personaje ya existe, mediante **[findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/findIndex)** y validamos si ese índice es mayor a 0.

Si es menor a 0, se agrega ya que por defecto al no encontrar una coincidencia, `findIndex` devuelve un **-1**; en caso contrario, si es mayor o igual a 0, se actualiza el objeto correspondiente.

**[Acá](https://codesandbox.io/s/creacion-o-actualizacion-segun-propiedad-2xx37)** te dejo el ejemplo completo para tu análisis. Si tienes alguna duda, me la dejas en los comentarios.

Saludos!